How can I improve this question about the justification of logic?
It's unclear to me how my question What justification do we have for using and trusting logic in domains that lack empirical (scientific) verification? merely pushes a personal philosophy. At least I don't think my question is asking "Is my personal philosophy X right?" which is the official explanation given by the site as the reason for closure. Judging by the comments, it looks like logic has a privileged holy place in the epistemological hearts of many, and so it's possible that the mere suggestion that its epistemic certainty could be doubted is perceived as unsettling, unorthodox, and worth punishing with a close vote.
How can the question be salvaged?

I agree.
This comment (on a different question) elaborates further:

I think closing the question within one hour from opening is rude and inconsiderate. It looks more like a gang activity (to me). Unless the question violates some rules, it should be able to stay open at least 24 hours, for other members to be able to weigh in.

Here is why this abuse of SE norms is occuring.
We should wonder the absurdity of closing philosophical questions as "personal philosophy"

Cogito Ergo Sum is Descartes personal philosophy (PP)
I know that I do not know is Socrates PP
All against All is Hobbes PP
Life is not a problem to be solved but a reality to be experienced  is Kierkegaard PP
God is dead is Nietzsche's (much misunderstood) PP
It does not matter how slowly you go as long as you do not stop is Confucius PP
Brahman is real; the world is unreal; the world is Brahman is Shankara's PP
Knowing others is knowledge; knowing yourself is wisdom is Lao Tzu PP
etc etc etc

In short there can be no philosophy without personal philosophy.
This is less true elsewhere:

Its harder to call relativity as Einstein's personal physics
Even if Bohr, Schrödinger, Heisenberg disagreed with him, whose combined philosophy, different from Einstein's is also not so personal
Even in something creative like music one would find that Mozart and Haydn sound similar enough that automatic AI generators make decent imitations of genres.

¿Objective Truth?
A deeper and more subtle problem relates to the nature of objective truth or just reality.

Einstein and Bohr may argue on the philosophy of God playing dice
Mach and Boltzman may argue on the purely philosophical question (at that time) re. the reality of atoms
Frege and Mill may dispute the philosophy of logicism vs psychologism of logic
Hilbert and Brouwer may argue about the philosophy of math
and so on

So people in any field may in the last resort punch holes in the foundations of their field.
Where do philosophers go?
The standard tautology sounding answer is that philosophy arguments are philosophy arguments.
A less tautological version is Meta-philosophy is philosophy
So meta-mathematics, meta-physics etc becomes philosophy etc but
we have no outside, just possible opinions — or philosophies!
Philosophers have nowhere more foundational to go!
The inexorable conclusion is that there is no "outside" of philosophy.
So nothing can be off-topic philosophically.
[Note: Questions may still need to be closed but this can only be for logistical, administrative, political etc reasons. So What is a woman? is a a fine philosophical question in principle but not tolerable in the current climate]

If a question doesn't belong here, then we shouldn't ignore that fact for some amount of hours or days just to be polite. You can interpret swift moderation and enforcing quality standards and rules as "rude and inconsiderate" or "gang activity", but those things are necessary if you want to have quality standards, and it's how things work here.

There seems to be some confusion about why questions are closed in that comment, because it acknowledges that violating rules would merit prompt closure... but that's why questions are promptly closed, and questions that don't violate rules or guidelines shouldn't at any point be closed, whether within an hour or after a year. If it shouldn't have been closed within an hour, then it also shouldn't have been closed after a year. So the issue boils down to "should the question have been closed at all", not whether it should've been closed within an hour.

The "personal philosophy" close reason explains why those questions don't belong here: "Questions that push a personal philosophy with no question beyond 'am I right' or 'what do you think' are off-topic here as this is not a blog. It's ok to express unique opinions, but you must have an actual, answerable question to go with them.". This is a Q&A and questions should actually be questions. None of the "personal philosophy" things you said are questions (even if one could ask questions about them, or mention them in answers). But does "personal philosophy" apply to this question? Probably not.

@NotThatGuy »...But does "personal philosophy" apply to this question? Probably not.« There you are! Which also indicates the issue with your earlier comments. What's the point of talking of rules if the rules are not being followed consistently? Or at the least there are diverse interpretations extant? And no one is bothering even to "agree to disagree". Ppl are just merrily going their own way
